# Smart keyboard internalization for IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

When I start IntelliJ IDEA, that message comes up, but I couldn't find any information about that feature and how it could help me.

> Enable smart keyboard internalization for IDEA.: We have found out that you are using a non-english keyboard layout.
>   You can enable smart layout support for German language.You can change this option in the settings of IDEA more...

Comment: Interesting. I never git that popup even though I am using a German keyboard too and the latest IDEA version.

If you press the "Help" button in Settings => Keymap, then the feature is mentioned, but not really described.

Also in the registry (Ctrl-Shift-A, then type "registry") there is an option "ide.non.english.keyboard.layout.fix" with quite bland description "Enables a fix for key codes with non-English keyboard layouts".

Comment: It shows up when I press the CTRL key for the first time after start of the IDE.

Comment: [From the help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/keymap.html?page=1):
_<language> layout support - This check box appears when a non-English keyboard layout has been detected. When you type any character in the editor, the keyboard layout is recognized and a notification appears.
This option is available for Windows and Linux only. If you don't see this option, it means either you are using OS X or WebStorm didn't detect any of the supported input locales._

Does not speak about what it does  when it's enabled though...

Comment: It seems they have been working on this on OSX as well, but this does not work as expected : [IDEA-156990](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156990) and [IDEA-156986](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156986)

Answer (score 3):

This dialog has been introduced on [Github](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/737faf33e7734b0d1b96d7bca88a1a1b0179f7d0) as fix for [IDEA-63779](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63779). 
It fixes certain keyboard shortcut clashes with non-english keyboard layouts. Cited from [IntelliJ support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207136015-Smart-keyboard-internalization-):

> This option enables support for certain hotkeys with "de", "fr", "it" and "uk" layouts. Without it some combinations will not work (like AltGr+7 to type "[" with German keyboard).

There are corresponding [Linux](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-215) and [Windows](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-216) issues as well.